# How can I use localStorage to store the value/data IN a form in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use localStorage to store the data of a form. Here is the code:

```
<form>

<textarea id="txt" placeholder="Type in some text!"></textarea>

</form>
```

Comment: Use [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to get the values, and [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store data like this

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
//for your example
var txtValue = document.getElementById("txt").value;

localStorage.setItem("txt", txtValue);
```

To get the value you can do like:

```
localStorage.getItem("txt");
```

Comment: it works, is there a way to put it in a function???

Comment: yes, how do you want to use it? can you give me more details about the function

Comment: You just click a button and then it would save, and then on the load of the page the text in the form you saved should be there

Comment: Check  here: https://codepen.io/hasip-timurtas/pen/PozjEyL you can use this function